# Error comparing pandas DataFrame with datetime

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, pandas

I'm trying to perform comparison between Pandas DataFrame and Datetime objects.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [ datetime(2000, 1, 1)]})

# Works fine
test1 = df['date'] >= datetime(2000, 1, 2)
# Returns error
test2 = datetime(2000, 1, 2) <= df['date']
```

which results in this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-950-a1d9be25e98f> in <module>()
      7 test1 = df['date'] >= datetime(2000, 1, 2)
      8 # Returns error
----> 9 test2 = datetime(2000, 1, 2) <= df['date']

TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to Series
```

Why doesn't the second comparison work? Is there a bug or is this a non-correct way to perform the comparison?

---

Running:
python 2.7, pandas 0.18, Windows 2010 server, anaconda

Comment: what is your numpy version as this works for me: `test2
Out[222]:
0    False
Name: date, dtype: bool`

Comment: @EdChum I have numpy 1.10.4 installed in py27 but this doesnt work for me. What is your version of numpy?

Comment: np is `1.10.4` pandas is `0.18.0` but python 3.4 64-bit

Answer (score 3):

I'm fairly certain that this is a quirk of Python2.7's datetime comparisons:

Consider the following script that compares a `datetime` object to an object that will compare equal to any object that raised `NotImplemented` when compared to any object.

```
from datetime import datetime

class ComparesEqualClass(object):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self == other

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return False

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return False

    __req__ = __eq__
    __rne__ = __ne__
    __rlt__ = __lt__
    __rgt__ = __gt__

ComparesEqual = ComparesEqualClass()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(ComparesEqual < datetime(2001, 1, 1))
    print(datetime(2001, 1, 1) < ComparesEqual)
```

Running on 2.7:

```
$ python2.7 comp_demo.py
False
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "comp_demo.py", line 29, in <module>
    print(datetime(2001, 1, 1) < ComparesEqual)
TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to ComparesEqualClass
```

And on 3.5:

```
$ python3.5 comp_demo.py
False
False
```

I imagine that the 2.7 `datetime` object is a bit too strict when comparing on the right. Just make sure that the Dataframe is on the left hand side of comparators and you should have no problems, since the Dataframe's `__lt__` or `__le__` or whatever method will be called.